# Kanji Stroke Endings

Tags: discussion, kanji

I'm just getting started learning my first kanji and finding stroke order for every kanji is easy online. However, what I can't seem to find is an online dictionary or other resource that tells you the stroke ending for each stroke (とめる、はねる、はらう). Does anyone know of such resources?

Comment: I'm guessing then that from the number of views, such online resources don't really exist then

Comment: Does someone have an answer they can offer?